# How to use pyodbc on a .accdb file linked to a sharepoint list

Tags: python, ms-access, sharepoint, pyodbc, sharepoint-list

I'm having issues with the following lines of code:

```py
print("Before")

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project Folders\\sharepointList\\test.accdb;')

print("After")
```

I printed small messages before and after this line to narrow down where my program was stopping.

When I run my script I do not get an error message, the program simply stops. I know the program stops because the second print statement never happens.

the `test.accdb` file referred to is linked to a SharePoint list. I am using SharePoint 2016.

I tried this same line of code with a different .accdb file, one that was not linked to a SharePoint list. The code finished and printed both print statements when I ran it. This leads me to believe that the issue is due to my list being linked to Sharepoint.

Here is the entirety of the code I am trying to run

```py
import pyodbc

print("Before")

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project Folders\\sharepointList\\test.accdb;')

print("After")
```

I replaced my actual username with `userName` but everything else is accurate.

I expect the `conn` variable to allow me to create a cursor, and from there allow me to add data to my .accdb file using `pyodbc`.

Instead, I can't get past assigning something to the `conn` variable.

Comment: This is being discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/608).